# How to update data in a different ViewController and show it in the parent?

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview

I asked a similar question a while back, but I'm clearly missing something.

I have 2 view controllers - one that displays the data and one where data is edited. In my first controller, I create my object:

```
thing = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Thing" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

thing.DateTime = [NSDate date];
thing.aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12000];
```

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I then create a new controller and add some of this data:

```
ThingDetailController *thingDetailController = [[ThingDetailController alloc] initwithDateTime:thing.DateTime];

thingDetailController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:thingDetailController animated:YES];
[thingDetailController release];
```

In my initWithDateTime initializer, I assign the DateTime that is passed in to my ThingDetailController.dateTime object:

```
- (id)initWithDateTime:(NSDate *)dateStamp {

    dateTime = dateStamp;
    return self;
}
```

When my new controller appears on the screen, that data is present and usable, but any changes I make there are not sent back to the parent controller when I tap the back button in the detail editor controller.

What do I need to do to make this value changeable in that area ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

The data is updated but the view does not automatically refresh from that data.  If your first view controller is a `UITableViewController` then you should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController` and using its delegate methods to detect data changes.  Otherwise your view has no idea that the data has changed unless you tell it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I am using a NSFetchedResultsController in the parent view, and I do have the controllerDidChangeContent delegate in the ParentController. What else should I be doing ?

Comment: Saving the context as the delegate does not fire until a save is called.